# No boot after resizing my hard drive ubuntu 12.04

Tags: boot, grub2

After resizing my partition using gparted I've been enable to boot from my hard drive getting the error "Non system disk or disk error replace and strike ..."

Now I can only access my system with a usb using ''Super Grub2 Disk''

I tried all the methods on the net to rescue my grub but none of them worked here is what "boot repair" created trying to fix my boot please help me.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/1542979/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved I was flagging the wrong partition to boot
What I had to do is just flag the whole  extended partition not only the  booting one